# How to check connectivity timeout for android apache connectivity

Tags: android

**What i am doing**:: I am checking internet connectivity using this code in a Async task with a `timeout`, it returns `true` if connectivity is available returns `false` if connectivity is not available

```
public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection() {
            try {

                HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(500); 
                urlc.connect();
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Log", "Error checking internet connection", e);
            }
        return false;
    }
```

**How can i do the same for apache Http client below**:

```
public static String doConnection(String url) {
        HttpGet httpget=null;
        String mContent=null;
        HttpClient Client=null;

        Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        mContent = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

        return mContent;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just surround execute with a try and do the same as you did in the 1st piece of code?

Comment: @user3249477 ...... Yes i can but i am not aware on how to give the timeout .... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this out:

```
HttpGet httpget=null;
String mContent=null;
HttpClient Client=null;

Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
Client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 500);
httpget = new HttpGet(url);
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
try {
    mContent = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
    return true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return false;
```

Report errors if any.

EDIT: This looks cleaner:

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 500);

    Client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```